# Devise "only lower case letters, numbers, and '_' allowed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

i'm having a problem with devise.
 I ran `rails generate devise:install`
then I ran `rails generate devise User`

I'm getting this error message when i try to run `rake db:migrate`:

```
Illegal name for migration file: /Users/jacobchristiansen/12in12/reddit/db/migrate/20150116195344_devise_create_devise:installs.rb
    (only lower case letters, numbers, and '_' allowed)
```

I'm using rails 4.2.0 and ruby 2.2.0

Comment: Your problem is that you have `:installs` in migration's name 20150116195344_devise_create_devise:installs.rb  Rename it to `20150116195344_devise_create_devise.rb` and it should be ok.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but forgot to delete the :installs from the migration file as well. It works now :)